# How to force MSIExec to upgrade to the specified version

Tags: installation, libreoffice, windows-installer

I'd like to install LibreOffice (version 5.3.2.2) as a part of another installation but I'm having following issue:

- When a version 4.x or earlier is already installed, the installer installs LibreOffice 5.3.2.2, as expected.
- When nothing is installed, the installer installs LibreOffice 5.3.2.2, as expected.
- When a version 5.x is already installed, the installer does nothing.

Which parameter can I add to the commandline in order to force the update from 5.x to 5.3.2.2? Currently I'm using following commandline:

```
msiexec /i "<filename.msi>" /q
```

I've already tried the parameter `REINSTALL=ALL` but this was not working (no update from 5.x to 5.3.2.2).

In case some modifications needs to be done to the MSI file: I have Orca on my PC, so I can modify the MSI file where needed.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Daniel: Orca is an MSI editor, which I could use to alter the MSI file, in case there are no parameters which can do what I want.

Comment: I removed the tag because it does not help classify the question. The tag is present on [three other questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/orca) and none of these refer to the MSI editor. They refer to the Orca Screen Reader instead.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I had no idea that other program existed :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meanwhile I've found the answer to my question, using Windows-installer SDK:

```
msiexec /i "<filename.msi>" /q REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=A
```

(the `REINSTALLMODE=A` forces all files to be re-installed, whether or not they are same/different/older/younger/...)

Comment: Your command will install the program only in C drive. With my command option you can control the destination folder. And it is helpful if your C drive is somehow damaged.

Answer (score 0):

- Download latest LibreOffice from this site:: https://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/
- The syntax to unpack an MSI file is pretty simple, the following can be inserted into the Run box, Command Prompt or your own script.

`msiexec /a pathtoMSIfile /qb TARGETDIR=pathtotargetfolder`

- The “/qb” argument tells the installer to display a simple UI while unpacking, if you wish to make the process completely silent use “/qn” instead.

[image: Msiexec]

- Let, say I have a LibreOffice MSI file in F drive and I want to install it in E drive. I just type the command as administrator

`msiexec /a "F:\LibreOffice_5.3.3_Win_x64.msi" /qb TARGETDIR=E:\Libreoffice`

Here are the two images showing the progress of installation
[image: Libreoffice Initial]
[image: Libreoffice time]

- This process overwrites all the previous installation files in that target directory. Remember to **copy all the dlls** from `Libreoffice\System64` to `Libreoffice\program`. I make a shortcut with `E:\Libreoffice\program\soffice.exe --nologo` ( in my case) from which I can open any compatible office files by just drag & drop. You may install the program other than system drive.
- There are also some apps to install MSI, try these:: [LessMSI](https://github.com/activescott/lessmsi), [Universal Extractor](https://www.legroom.net/software/uniextract), [MSI Unpacker Utility](http://www.jsware.net/jsware/msicode.php5#unpack)

Comment: That sounds like a not-so-great idea. It won’t update component registrations (if any) and most certainly not the version recorded in the MSI database.

Comment: @DanielB I use it everyday with this process and nothing wrong ever happened. One may manually open a file with a right click and select "open with". And there is no registration required.

Comment: @Biswa: thanks for the elaborated reply, but I was expecting something which looked like `msiexec /i <filename>.msi <WHAT_TO_DO>=<OVERWRITE_EXISTING>` (pardon the capital letters), I've been looking in Windows-installer's SDK but I didn't find it. And in case this does not exist, could I achieve this by editing <filename>.msi using an MSI editor (like Orca)?

Comment: This process does not require any SDK executable. Msiexec is an Windows in-build software. And with that command option you can install it anywhere.